# Find the most recent month an account has entered arrears?

Tags: sql, sql-server

| Primary Key | AccountID | Date | Arrears |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 50 | 30/04/2023 | 0 |
| 2002 | 50 | 31/03/2023 | 0 |
| 2003 | 50 | 28/02/2023 | 0 |
| 2004 | 50 | 31/01/2023 | 0 |
| 2005 | 50 | 31/12/2022 | 0 |
| 2006 | 50 | 30/11/2022 | 0 |
| 2007 | 50 | 31/10/2022 | 0 |
| 2008 | 50 | 30/09/2022 | 0 |

| Primary Key | AccountID | Date | Arrears |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 111 | 30/04/2023 | 100 |
| 10002 | 111 | 31/03/2023 | 100 |
| 10003 | 111 | 28/02/2023 | 100 |
| 10004 | 111 | 31/01/2023 | 0 |
| 10005 | 111 | 31/12/2022 | 250 |
| 10006 | 111 | 30/11/2022 | 250 |
| 10007 | 111 | 31/10/2022 | 250 |
| 10008 | 111 | 30/09/2022 | 250 |

| Primary Key | AccountID | Date | Arrears |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3111 | 75 | 30/04/2023 | 200 |
| 3112 | 75 | 31/03/2023 | 200 |
| 3113 | 75 | 28/02/2023 | 200 |
| 3114 | 75 | 31/01/2023 | 200 |
| 3115 | 75 | 31/12/2022 | 200 |
| 3116 | 75 | 30/11/2022 | 200 |
| 3117 | 75 | 31/10/2022 | 200 |
| 3118 | 75 | 30/09/2022 | 200 |

I've included 3 sections of the table. For the first section no date should be returned as the account hasn't been in arrears. For the second 28/02/2023(most recent month entering arrears). For the third it should be  30/09/2022. I'm aggregating on AccountID my current attempt is:

```
SELECT ACCOUNTID, MAX(DATE) + 1
FROM ARREARS_TBL 
GROUP BY ACCOUNTID , ARREARS 
HAVING ARREARS = 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **gaps-and-islands** problem.

You need to use `LEAD` to get the next row's data for each row, then take the first row which has more than 0 but the row after it is 0 or non-existent.

```sql
SELECT
  AccountID, Date
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          nextArrears = LEAD(Arrears) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY Date DESC)
        FROM ARREARS_TBL a
    ) withNext
    WHERE Arrears > 0 AND (nextArrears = 0 OR nextArrears IS NULL)
) filtered
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/FUOUYnMB)

Answer (score 1):

First, the count(alll,allzero,Notzerro) and minimum date of the Arrears is calculated

In the second step, the one that is all zero should be removed by comparison (if the total count  is equal to count zero).

In the third step, they check if everything is non-zero, the last date is displayed, otherwise the minimum date of the Arrears is displayed

```
with _list as (

    select 
                   AccountID
                   ,PrimaryKey
                   ,date_,
                  case when  Arrears =0 then
                                         lag(date_) over(partition by AccountID order by date_  desc) 
                 else null end as lgdate
                 , sum(case when  Arrears >0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by AccountID order by (select 0) desc) Count_NotZero
                 , sum(case when  Arrears =0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by AccountID order by (select 0)  desc) Count_Zero
                 , count(*) over(partition by AccountID order by (select 0)) Count_All
 

                from rr
), _listCal as (

                select 
                            AccountID
                            ,PrimaryKey
                            ,case
                                    when a.Count_NotZero=Count_All then
                                    LAST_VALUE(date_) over(partition by AccountID order by (select 0)  desc)
                                    else 
                                    first_value( lgdate) over(partition by AccountID order by lgdate  desc)
                                    end as finaldate
                            ,row_number( ) over(partition by AccountID order by (select 0)   desc) as rw

                from  _list a
                where a.Count_All!=a.Count_Zero 

)
select AccountID,PrimaryKey,finaldate
from _listCal
where rw=1
order by PrimaryKey
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SA01Ofpu)

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
        row_number() over(partition by AccountID order by date) as rn,
        sum(case when Arrears = 0 then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by AccountID) as total,
        count(1) over(partition by AccountID) as count,
        lag(Arrears) over(partition by AccountID order by date) as lag_pos
  from mytable
)
select AccountID, Date
from cte
where total > 0 AND ( (total = count and rn = 1) or lag_pos = 0)
order by AccountID, rn
```

This will eliminate any AccountID having `Arrears = 0` only by the condition `total > 0`

If no `Arrears = 0` exists in a specific account then we will take the latest date.

if `Arrears = 0` Exists then will take the next date (`lag_pos = 0`)

Result :

```
AccountID   Date
75          2022-09-30 00:00:00.000
111         2023-02-28 00:00:00.000
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/YvPFuqdg)